# Asp.net Membership and Simple Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

What is the difference between Simple Membership and Membership in asp.net? Is Simple Membership introduced in mvc 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET membership was the traditional approach for authentication, authorization from the microsoft team.But, with the release of mvc 4, they introduced new improved version with name Simple Membership.Simple membership relies on Extended Membership Provider

Behind the scenes, the SimpleMembershipProvider and the ExtendedMembershipProvider, as well as DotNetOpenAuth are all at work.
These changes was the need, because many web sites no longer want to store user credentials locally. Instead, they want to use OAuth and OpenID so someone else is responsible for keeping passwords safe, and people coming to the site have one less password to invent (or one less place to share an existing password). With these changes it is easy to authenticate a user via Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft, or Google. All you need to do is plugin the right keys.

Summary:

1)SimpleMembership has been designed as a replacement for the previous ASP.NET Role and Membership provider system.

2)SimpleMembership solves common problems developers ran into with the Membership provider system and was designed for modern user / membership / storage needs.

3)SimpleMembership integrates with the previous membership system, but you can't use a MembershipProvider with SimpleMembership.

4)The new ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application template AccountController requires SimpleMembership and is not compatible with previous MembershipProviders.

5)You can continue to use existing ASP.NET Role and Membership providers in ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 4 - just not with the ASP.NET MVC 4 AccountController.

6)The existing ASP.NET Role and Membership provider system remains supported, as it is part of the ASP.NET core.

7)ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms does not use SimpleMembership; it implements OAuth on top of ASP.NET Membership.
Hope, you got the clear concept of your question.